# c# How to draw same 3D model twice, from two different camera positions?

Tags: c#, 3d, camera, xna, xna-4.0

Using C#/XNA 4.0: (but the question is code-independent)
I'm trying to make a "viewscreen/security camera" style feature: i.e. a 3D model that is rendered first in the main screen, from a (globally) fixed camera angle - as well as in a small "window"-like box, in say the upper right corner, from a fixed (in relation to the 3D model) camera point.

To demonstrate what I'm aiming for, here's a short clip from the Pixar Cars "Tokyo Mater" short, probably illegally uploaded, showing both the primary image being rendered in the background, as well as (two) smaller subwindows, showing the same scene from slightly different angles (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdPt8-ypLmI#t=02m09s)  Why is this my example?  Probably because my 3 year old has watched it so many times that it's seared into my mind, but we digress....

The first part works fine, I have  models happily moving about the space and they're all rendered properly and in the right locations.

Here's how that looks:

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in theirModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] 
                    * Matrix.CreateScale(.03f)
                    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(theirmodelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(theirmodelPosition); // "real" world model location happens to be (0,0,-100000)

                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(
                    cameraPosition, // main screen camera location, happens to be 0,3500,10000
                    Vector3.Zero,
                    Vector3.Up);

                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), 
                    .5f, 
                    nearClippingDistance,             
                   farClippingDistance);                           
            }
            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw(); 
        }
```

But the sub-window part is giving me difficulty.  Here's what I'm trying: (code runs immediately after the above in the draw sequence)

```
 foreach (ModelMesh mesh in theirModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] 
                    * Matrix.CreateScale(.03f)
                    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(theirmodelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(theirmodelPosition); // same as above

                    effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(
                        //cameraPosition,                        
                        new Vector3(
          theirmodelPosition.X, 
          theirmodelPosition.Y, 
          theirmodelPosition.Z - 12000, // sub-window camera location, fixed in front of model
                        Vector3.Zero, 
                        Vector3.Up);                    

                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), 
                    .5f, 
                    nearClippingDistance,
                    farClippingDistance);

            }
            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw(); 
 }
```

}

I tried to keep everything the same and change the cameraposition for the 2nd draw to just be fixed in relation to the model's location, but this results in the 2nd draw being in the center of the screen, instead of (for example) the upper right - and if I change the camera location to be in the upper right, it upsets the angle it is looking at the object.  There's other problems as well, such as if the model's position varies in (for example) the Y axis in addition to the Z axis, the sub-window camera slowly drifts out of alignment, but I think they all stem from the same issue: just changing the camera position in relation to the model and then re-drawing isn't sufficient.

So here's the general question, rather than trying to debug any specific issues I might have above: given a standard world, view and projection matrix that properly renders a normal 3D model, what parts of those 3 matrices (I assume, perhaps wrongly, in the View one) need to change to also render that model *again* (and or any backgrounds/other models near it, that would be within the field of view) at (X,Y) on the screen, from a fixed camera angle (Z) distance from that model?

Thanks in advance, and my apologies if I've asked the question inartfully.

Comment: Simple Mechanical 101 question.  The difference between the two models is the location of camera 1 (x,y,z, angle) - camera 2 (x,y,z, angle).  the problem is simplified if the angles of the two camera are the same.  When the camera angles are different you have to be smart to simplify the solution.  I would keep y, and z the same.  Make one angle +10 degrees with plus +X and the 2nd camera -10 degrees with -X.

Comment: Turns out that I wasn't able to find the solution because I didn't know the proper terms to search for, but finally I think I found it.  For anyone else's reference who finds this question and similarly doesn't know about "viewports", here's what I found that is (from what I can tell) designed to do what I'm trying to do: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313965.aspx

Comment: Also, when XNA was popular, Microsoft wrote many samples that are stored in the education section of the their XNA web site. Here is link to XNA specific code sample of a split screen: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/split_screen